# Did J.K. Rowling purposefully name the school founders off of Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, jk-rowling

So there are four Houses (and four Founders): Hufflepuff, Gryffindor, Ravenclaw, and Slytherin.

Hmm. HGRS. What does that spell? Oh right! Hogwarts!

Did J. K. Rowling do that on purpose?

Comment: @Valorum But this is like, something else. I worded it wrong.

Comment: Also linked to this one; [Why did JK Rowling choose the name 'Hogwarts'?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/100229/why-did-jk-rowling-choose-the-name-hogwarts?rq=1).

Comment: @Valorum I mean't the school founders.

Comment: I see no evidence in the dupes that the name related in any way to the founder's names.

Comment: @Valorum nonono I mean, are the *school founders' names* based off of Hogwarts.

Comment: Possibly a dupe of [Why is Hufflepuff House called Hufflepuff?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/57128/why-is-hufflepuff-house-called-hufflepuff)

Comment: The suggested duplicate is not a duplicate of this in any way but the 2 suggest in comments are... dunno how to fix that...

Comment: @Durakken in theory he(valorum) could open and redupe  but since he already listed the other 2 its prob fine.

Comment: There should have been two more houses. Whompakep (for the ones too violent to get into Slytherin; emblem: a Whomping Willow) and Troldebok (for the ones too dumb to get into Hufflepuff; emblem: a booger).

Comment: Don't forget Overbearing - for people too nosey for Racenclaw ;)

Comment: I always thought it was RGSH - or Ragoush, whicg is a delightful soup served on Merlin's birthday

Answer (score 9):

## It’s unclear if this was intended or simply a  coincidence.

There’s nowhere that JKR ever mentioned that the name Hogwarts contains the initials of all the Founders, or whether this was intentional.

Relying only on logic and common sense, since there’s no “official” information on this, it’s hard to reason out a definitive answer in this case. It’s entirely possible that it was intended, *but* it’s not sufficiently clear that it *can’t* plausibly or reasonably be seen as unintentional (like how Diagon Alley is clearly a pun on “diagonally” even though that’s never “officially” confirmed).

Comment: And Diagon Alley/diagonally is used as a plot point when Harry ends up in Knockturn Alley after using the Floo and mispronouncing Diagon Alley.

Answer (score 3):

A google search showed me [this tumblr page](http://livelaughlovetoread.tumblr.com/post/15130218984) , where a potterhead defines this connection as

> H G R S Is in Hogwarts for a reason, and that reason is House unity.

There are also other sites showing this connection, but couldn't find any official J.K. Rowling announcement. So after reading [why Hogwarts is named Hogwarts ?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/100229/why-did-jk-rowling-choose-the-name-hogwarts?rq=1) I believe that she found the name Hogwarts first and then derived the house names from it. Not the other way around.

But I didn't see that connection until I read this question. I read every book minimum 3 times(if not more)